# Unable to Resolve errors while adding file download code to webview app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Trying to make a web view app for a site. although everything works fine, unable to resolve few errors that are popping up while I add this "file download" code.

Here's the android code :

**Activity Main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.appgrep.urstudymate;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int FCR = 1;
    WebView webView;
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = null;
                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_sample);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
        assert webView != null;

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("https://urstudymate.com/");


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
                File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        storageDir      /* directory */
                );
                return imageFile;

            }
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        , "AndroidExampleFolder");
                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                // Create camera captured image file path and name
                File file = new File(
                        imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                + ".jpg");
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                // Set camera intent to file chooser
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                        , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType,
                                        String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

        });

    }


    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.super_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.myMenuOne:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.myMenuTwo:
                GoForward();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
    private void GoForward() {
        if (webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.goForward();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't go further!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**Super Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.filechooser.file.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/myMenuOne" android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" android:title="Item" app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/myMenuTwo" android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" android:title="Item" app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.appgrep.urstudymate">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However the piece of code I added is :

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
   DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
   myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
           
   myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
      DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
      myManager.enqueue(myRequest);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

(which i added already for which I got error at "setDownloadListener", "DownloadListener", "DownloadManager" and so on. almost all words in that piece.)

**SCREENSHOT :**
[image: screenshot of errors]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of errors? Be specific please.

Comment: @blackapps errors like "cannot resolve symbols" and "cannot resolve methods" and such

Comment: Put the mouse in "DownloadListener". After that press <Alt>+<Enter>.

Comment: @blackapps i did that for others while "setDownloadListener" is still at red with no resolution on hover along with URL, userAgent, contentDisposition and memetype etc.

Comment: Please post a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your patience, added the screenshot to the question

Comment: I see `new void DownloadListener()`. But the posted code shows `new DownloadListener()` which is correct. How is it possible that it differs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221557/discussion-between-harish-k-and-blackapps).

Comment: Why? I will not chat.